# MongoDb - Insert array in order

Tags: mongodb

I have a straight forward insert from a json file. The parsed collection from the Json is in the correct order, but MongoDb does not insert them in the same order.

```
    db.collection('Menu').count({}, function(err, numOfDocs){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    if(numOfDocs === 0){
        var navData = fs.readFileSync('./data/_seed/menu/nav.json', {encoding: 'utf8'});

        // navJson is in the correct order
        var navJson = JSON.parse(navData);

        db.collection('Menu').insert(navJson, function(err, results){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log('Successful seeding of navigation with ' + results.length + ' items.');
            }
        })
    };
});
```

I tried a _.each to no avail. How can I ensure MongoDb inserts the items in the same order as the navJson?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

**As you can see, what is item [0] in the Json is item [5] in Mongo**

Comment: Can you reproduce in a small example you can post here. There should generally be nothing that would change the positions of array elements here. That is generally the point of an array structure, to maintain positional order.

Comment: You know the main reason there is a minimal reputation level to even post an image as part of your post is because it's generally the wrong thing to do and is not very useful. Case in point, a screenshot where the textual content would have been more appropriate. But also since there is nothing to compare with then we cannot see the comparison. I said **reproducible example**. Can you do that?

Comment: Is it in the reverse order of the JSON file you have in compare to mongodb array ?

Comment: No, with the exception of the 1st one, everything is in order. I even changed the success console print to print out the results array and they are also in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB as other SQL and NoSQL databases now guarantee to you default order.

If you need fix order of elements then you should make in your data structure and use it for insert and select.